# Split in 2 columns add to cart button and variable forms

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm struggling to separate variation form from the add to cart button in 2 columns.

Here is what I need:

[image]

The data inside the squer comes from a third party plugin called "TM Extra Product Options"

I'm using WP Bakery to build the layout as a "content template".

I've created these shortcodes:

```
    /* from tm extra options plugi. show final price */
    
function preco_final() {
        do_action( 'teste' );
    }
    add_shortcode('precofinal', 'preco_final');
    
    /*from tm extra optins plugin. show extra fields */
    
function opcoes_extras() {
        do_action( 'campos_extras' );
    }
    add_shortcode('opcoesextras', 'opcoes_extras');
    
    /* here is where i'm trying to load only the add to cart button without the form */
    
function botao_comprar(){
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }
    add_shortcode('botao-comprar', 'botao_comprar');
```

In my experiments I've already manage to split the form from the button but when it happens the extra produt options form fades out!

I'm on this about a week and I already did everything I know. I hope someone colud help me on that.

Comment: Should just be able to do this with CSS by adjusting the layout assuming the mark-up within the HTML is written in a way that will allow this.  But being at the mercy of third-party plugins like WP Bakery and TM Extra Product Options, you just may not be able to.  Your best bet would be to inquire with their support teams.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.